# How do I make a pdf link within website open in a new window?

Tags: pdf, link, code

Is there an easy way to set a pdf link (link to a file within the website) open in a new window?
I am sure this must be something to do with the code, but it is the first time I have been asked to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Simply add **target="_blank"** in your anchor tag.

It will open pdf in new tab instead of same page.

```
<a href="https://www.clickdimensions.com/links/TestPDFfile.pdf" target="_blank" title="Read PDF">Open PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you opening this with a hyperlink?

If so just add the key target="_blank" to your hyperlink: Example:

```
<a href="url_to_your_pdf" target="_blank">Open</a>
```